# kivy android textinput focus box highlighting?

Tags: android, kivy

According to the docs:

> You can set the focus to a Textinput, meaning that the input box will be highlighted and keyboard focus will be requested

When I set focus to a `TextInput` box (either by touching the box or `text.focus = True`), the highlighting is barely visible.  For that matter, the cursor is also barely visible.

Is there a way to make the highlighting and cursor more obvious? In particular, I'd like a thicker border, perhaps colored, and a thicker cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visible focusing is basically changing one image into another - casual gray one into the one with bluish border.

Thicker *border* I don't think so, but with [this PR](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4745) you can change its *width*, which will result in a similar thing.

Then there's [`cursor_color`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.cursor_color) which allows you to change, obviously, color of the cursor. And that's probably everything you can do with cursor without directly messing with the internals.

About highlighted background and other related properties you can use [`background_active`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.background_active) and similar properties under that in the documentation. Those are *images* which are in [atlas](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png) by default, but you will use a casual separated image.